# Dynamically add nodes in an JTree

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

i have got a problem to add nodes dynamically to my JTree.

I receive my JTree Informations via a RestAPI in json Format.
The informations i need are the folderID and the folderName.

The folderID structure is like that:

```
1
1.1
6.8
7.1.1.1
1.2
etc.
```

So i need to define my nodelevel by the points of my folderIDs.
I have searched for some code and found this one.

[Dynamically add nodes in a JTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498106/dynamically-add-nodes-in-a-jtree?answertab=active#tab-top)

But when i implement the code i get an error message: root cannot be resolved to a variable

```
for(String s:list){
            String[] substr=s.split("\\.");
            String parent=substr[0];
            for(int i=1;i<substr.length-1;i++){
                parent=parent+ "." + substr[i];
            }
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node=null;
            node=findparentnode(parent,**root**);


            if(node==null)
                **root**.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(s));
            else
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(s));

        }
```

Could you help me find a solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the root first:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root")
JTree tree = new JTree(rootNode);
```

Then you can start to add nodes to the `JTree` by adding nodes to the root node.

Comment: futhermore * *root * * contains the operator * and won't compile

Comment: i have added it but i get an other error : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findparentnode(String, DefaultMutableTreeNode) from the type Main

Comment: as a quick-fix, make findparentnode static. based on the code you posted, I can't give you any other advice, because I don't know the rest of your class

Comment: @JEY the operator * i have inplementet to show you the position of my problem.

Comment: now i get my tree but the structure is not correct. i get for example 6.8 as a main folder. 6.8 should be the node of the main folder 6.
Any solutions ?